# Export to pdf not showing columns morethan 5 in angularjs uigrid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

i want to generate pdf but columns are exceeding the table border,i may get morethan 5 columns till 15 columns, so is their any way to do this so that i get all 15 columns in one sheet pdf, 
and i gave 
`exporterPdfOrientation: 'portrait',
    exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
    exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,`

this is my sample plunker
[sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qjkPe9fr8oTqqdLj6GiU?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 'portrait' to 'landscape'

Comment: Is their any way to adjust column width base on content in that?

Comment: column width works the same in both portrait and landscape.

Comment: i was telling about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716362/while-exporting-to-pdf-column-content-is-exceeding-the-column-border-in-uigrid