# while Exporting to PDF, column content is exceeding the column border in uigrid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

if i get the column data like this with no space in between

`$scope.gridOptions.data = [{"name":"rasheedsyedabdulhameed"}];`
and this is my gridoptions

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'name' }
],
enableGridMenu: true,
enableSelectAll: true,
exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
exporterPdfDefaultStyle: {fontSize: 9},
exporterPdfTableStyle: {margin: [30, 30, 30, 30]},
exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: {fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red'},
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", style: 'headerStyle' },
exporterPdfFooter: function ( currentPage, pageCount ) {
  return { text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount.toString(), style: 'footerStyle' };
},
exporterPdfCustomFormatter: function ( docDefinition ) {
  docDefinition.styles.headerStyle = { fontSize: 22, bold: true };
  docDefinition.styles.footerStyle = { fontSize: 10, bold: true };
  return docDefinition;
},
exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,
exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```

};

in export to pdf sheet the content is exceeding the column border, this is my example plunker [just a sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nqc8MsPnaBiw0EygKQIq?p=preview)

Comment: Found this example very useful, especially the footer/header properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: "*"` on each column to make it adjust to the content.  However, if the content is extremely large, your table may exceed the page size.